# how to style bxslider image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Having some trouble here styling my bxslider image slider. It also does not appear that it's taking whatever styles I've tried to give it, in the first place - but theres also the "prev" and "next" text links that i dont want either.

any chance someone can help trouble shoot where I need to make changes to style this to look more like this! -->  http://danielmdesigns.com/windermere/images/sliderexample.png

Let me know if you need something else, but to see this live, please visit http://www.danielmdesigns.com/windermere/index.html and my HTML CSS and JS are below as well;

HTML

```
 <ul class="bxslider">
 <li><img src="images/imagescroll_1.png" /></li>
 <li><img src="images/imagescroll_1.png" /></li>
 <li><img src="images/imagescroll_1.png" /></li>
 <li><img src="images/imagescroll_1.png" /></li>
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
.bxslider{
height:600px;
width:auto;
background-color:#c41230;
background-size:cover;
position:relative;
top:95px;
}
```

and my JS above the end body tag;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    captions: true,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: false
});
});
</script>
```

i really just need this to be full width with only the pager dots showing, positioned on top of my slider... any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted to make it full width with pager dots?

Comment: I have and nothing happens? So, not sure what im doing wrong. do i need to style the <li> instead?

Comment: to better explain myself... im having trouble making this full width. whatever im doing, does not seem to update/change. additionally, ive tried to remove the 1,2,3,4 text that appeared and cannot remove that either.

Comment: You need to include the bxSlider CSS file.

Comment: @KyleNeedham where exactly do I need to include this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Daniel-Maldondao Check the [bxSlider homepage](http://bxslider.com/) there is a 3 step guide to installing the slider.

Comment: I've got some help to figure it out. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to declare your custom CSS *after* you import the default .bxslider css file. That way you can override the defaults.